# Visual Studio anonymity

Tags: .net, obfuscation

Recently me and me colleague was wondering about obfuscating / removing project info. If application is reverse engineered than what kind of information the engineer sees?

Can he see the email of the person on which visual studio is registered to, or any valid informations which can lead to the author / authors?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen malware with windows usernames embedded. Likely there was much more metadata in those files. I guess using VS’ equivalent to `strip` may remove this kind of thing - but isn’t VS free now? Use another emailaddress, run it in a VM, make copies of the VM for other projects.

I’m aware Microsoft-hate is no longer en vogue, but I recommend e.g. cygwin or (especially) mingw if this is a concern for you. Microsoft is historically as evil as Intel and IBM, and have been very naughty in the past. The Melissa author got caught because of some stupid metadata, **included for no plausible reason except accountability**.

It’s not much use merely obfuscating your code, even teso’s burneye has been opened with a LKM (on linux, that is), and it is naive to think a process committed to memory can’t be dumped as a memory image/core. Sanitize your build environment, and don’t expect a company like Microsoft to release a development platform that isn’t forensics-friendly, given that most malware is written for that platform - using VS. Have a look at this:
http://thecyberrecce.net/2015/05/08/removing-debugging-information-from-visual-cc-projects/ .

... and many similar pages - google: visual studio anti-forensics